# How to Add or Remove Vue.js component dynamically (programmatically or on the fly)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Here is my code, this is just a example code, if the below works then this will help me to build something else that I am working on.

```
<template>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="divOne">
      <!-- Add or remove component here dynamically -->
    </div>
    <div id="divTwo">
      <!-- Add or remove component here dynamically -->
    </div>

    <!-- There will be more divs like #divOne #divTwo above -->

    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="one" value="divOne" v-model="pickedDiv">
      <label for="one">One</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="two" value="divTwo" v-model="pickedDiv">
      <label for="two">Two</label>
    </div>

    <button @click="addComponent">Add Component</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SomeComponent from './SomeComponent'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      pickedDiv: '',
      pickedDivPreviously: ''
      propItems: ['item1', 'item2']
    }
  }
  methods: {
    addComponent () {
      //-- This is not working code but I need something like this --//
      this.pickedDivPreviously = this.pickedDiv // event not sure how to get previously selected div

      const divThatIsPicked = document.getElementById(this.pickedDiv)
      const divThatWasPickedPreviously = document.getElementById(this.pickedDivPreviously)

      // code here to remove/empty/destroy old component from 'divThatWasPickedPreviously'
      divThatWasPickedPreviously.innerHTML = "" 

      // code here to add new component in 'divThatIsPicked'
      divThatIsPicked.appendChild('<some-component :someProp="propItems" @someEvent="someFn">')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I don't want to distract you from answering actual question but If you are curious about what I am working then check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/becjLtce/) :) Here I am trying to add new child DIV at the end of the row when any row item is clicked.

I will be more than happy if [this](https://jsfiddle.net/becjLtce/) is converted to vue than the actual question asked above, as said please don't get distracted from actual question if you find it hard :)

Comment: its possible. check this article : https://css-tricks.com/creating-vue-js-component-instances-programmatically/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got help from JamesThomson in [forum.vuejs.org](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-add-or-remove-vue-js-component-dynamically-programmatically-or-on-the-fly/32356/4), though the solution did not fix my issue but I got to understand the limitation or possibilities of using Vue.js.

JamesThomson says:

> Yeah, your example code definitely won’t work. When working with Vue
>   you need to think in a data oriented way, not DOM oriented (like
>   jQuery)
>
> Taken from your SO post:
>
> Here I am trying to add new child DIV at the end of the row when any
>   row item is clicked.
>
> I assume this is your end goal for this topic. A simple example of
>   this can be achieved like so:
>   https://codepen.io/getreworked/pen/XZOgbm?editors=1010

```js
let Welcome = {
  template: `
    <p @click="toggleMsg()">Welcome {{ msg }}!</p>
  `,
  
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'home'
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    toggleMsg () {
      return this.msg = this.msg === 'home' ? 'back' : 'home'; 
    }
  }
}

const App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    children: [
      Welcome
    ]
  },
  
  methods: {
    add () {
      this.children.push(Welcome);
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.rawgit.com/milligram/milligram/master/dist/milligram.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <template v-for="(child, index) in children">
      <component :is="child" :key="child.name"></component>
  </template>
  
  <button @click="add()">Add Another</button>
</div>
```

> or you can use a render function for more flexibility
>   https://jsfiddle.net/jamesbrndwgn/ku7m1dp0/9/

```js
const Reusable = {
  template: '<div>{{ name }} {{ bar }}</div>',
  
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  
  data () {
    return {
      bar: 'Bar'
    }
  }
}

const App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    items: []
  },
  
  methods: {
    addComponent () {
      const renderComponent = {
        render (h) {         
          return h(Reusable, {
            class: ['foo'],
            
            props: { 
              name: 'Foo'
            }
          })
        }
      }
      
      this.items.push(renderComponent)      
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.rawgit.com/milligram/milligram/master/dist/milligram.min.css">

<div id="app">
  <component v-for="item in items" ref="itemRefs" :is="item" :key="item.name"></component>
  
  <button @click="addComponent">Add Component</button>
</div>
```

I found one of the other ways that does kinda same as above but work only with old vue.js-1 not with vue.js-2:

```js
var createNewBox = function() {
 var MyPartial = Vue.extend({});
  window.partial = new MyPartial({
    template: '#partial',
    data: function() {
      return {
        txt: 'This is partial'
      }
    },
    methods: {
     print: function() {
        console.log('this.txt : ' + this.txt)
        console.log('main.txt : ' + main.txt)
      },
    },
  })
  window.partial.$mount().$appendTo('body')
}

window.main = new Vue({
  el: '#main',
  data: function() {
   return {
     txt: 'This is main'
    }
  },
  methods: {
   show: function() {
     createNewBox()
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue/1.0.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div @click="show" style="width:200px;height:200px;background:#000" id="main">
  <template id="partial">
    <div style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#ff0" @click.stop="print"></div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://jsfiddle.net/becjLtce/) converted to Vue.

https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/Kojpve

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child" @click="handleChildClick" data-new-child-id="1">1234</div>

    <div class="child" @click="handleChildClick" data-new-child-id="2">12341234 </div>

    <div class="child" @click="handleChildClick" data-new-child-id="3">123412341234</div>

    <div class="child" @click="handleChildClick" data-new-child-id="4">1234</div>

    <div class="new-child" v-if="[1,2,3,4].indexOf(showNewChild) > -1">boom</div>

    <div class="child" @click="handleChildClick" data-new-child-id="5">12341234</div>

    <div class="child" @click="handleChildClick" data-new-child-id="6">123412341234</div>

    <div class="child" @click="handleChildClick" data-new-child-id="7">1234</div>

    <div class="child" @click="handleChildClick" data-new-child-id="8">12341234</div>

    <div class="new-child" v-if="[5,6,7,8].indexOf(showNewChild) > -1">boom</div>

    <div class="child" @click="handleChildClick" data-new-child-id="9">123412341234</div>

    <div class="new-child" v-if="[9].indexOf(showNewChild) > -1">boom</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showNewChild:null
  },
  methods: {
    handleChildClick(e) {
      let id = e.target.dataset.newChildId;
      id = Number(id);
      this.showNewChild = id;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks for your help. There is still the problem, depending upon row item's content width we are not sure how many items will go in one row, hence not sure where to add this `<div class="new-child" v-if="[x,y,z].indexOf(showNewChild) > -1">boom</div>`

Comment: As said please don't get distracted from actual question if you find it hard, appreciate your help, thanks.